# How to serialize my data that are stored in C# dictionary into json object by using C# and json.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net-4.0, json.net

I have some data that are stored in the C# Dictionary.Now i want to serialize this dictionary objects to json format that i specified below...

This is my C# Code:

```
public void generateJsonString()
{
    StudInfo studDetails = new StudInfo();

    studDetails.GetQuestions.Add("s1", "Q1,Q2");
    studDetails.GetQuestions.Add("s2", "Q1,Q3");
    studDetails.GetQuestions.Add("s3", "Q4,Q5");

    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studDetails, Formatting.Indented);
}

public class StudInfo
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetQuestions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

It was given the output like below...

```
{
  "GetQuestions": {
    "s1": "Q1,Q2",
    "s2": "Q1,Q3",
    "s3": "Q4,Q5"
  }
}
```

But my required format is :

```
{
    GetQuestions:[
{
    "s1":"Q1,Q2",
    "s2":"Q3,Q4",
    "s3":"Q5,Q6",
}]
}
```

Needed update in the generated output is...(with respect to my required format)

1. I don't need double quote for GetQuestions
2. I want to create getQuestions as array object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studDetails);
```

Deserialize (If needed)

```
StudInfo = JsonConvert.Deserialize<StudInfo>(serializedString);
```

This will convert it back to a StudInfo object using generics and runtime safety.

Changing 
`Public Dictionary<string, string>` to `public List<Dictionary<string, string>>` will force it into an array once serialized.

Comment: Annoyingly I find Json.NET to be semi finicky on when it wraps the objects in arrays, sometimes it wraps them with only one object, sometimes it doesn't. However it always wraps if there is more then one.

Comment: your code generated the following output {
  "GetQuestions": {
    "GetQuestions": {
      "s1": "Q1,Q2",
      "s2": "Q1,Q3",
      "s3": "Q4,Q5"
    }
  }
}

Comment: whoops remove the anonymous object portion:

string serializedString = JsonConvert.Serialize(studDetails);

Comment: Yes i just put your line...But there is no method named Serialize in JsonConvert.So i modified like string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { GetQuestions = studDetails }, Formatting.Indented); in my source code i referred in my question

Comment: I see, I don't think you can remove the double quotes from the key, this should not matter in the least thought because any json serializer worth its salt will figure it out, as for making it an array, change your object to be List<Dictionary<string, string>> That will make it an array

Comment: @Saravanan please don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if it was helpful for you.